# What property is treated differently in Firefox that is preventing it from displaying this properly

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css, web

Okay, I've been working on creating a drop-down menu which has been working well on Google's Chrome. I recently expanded to check the site on Opera, Firefox & Safari.

Safari looks identical to Chrome but Opera and Firefox are showing the 'hidden' text of my drop-down menu. Opera is also not seeming to register paddings at all but my question is:

Q: What element is not being displayed in Firefox the same as it is in Chrome and Safari?

The way I am hiding my menu is by setting the height equal to 0px and then on hover setting it to the proper 30px. I choose this manner as it can be transitioned to have the menu glide up and down.

The HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="services.html" class="glow">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="researchDevelopment.html" class="glow">Research &amp; Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="designAudit.html" class="glow">Design Auditing</a></li>
                <li><a href="training.html" class="glow">Training</a></li>
                <li><a href="licensing.html" class="glow">Licensing</a></li>
                <li><a href="troubleshooting.html" class="glow">Troubleshooting &amp; Performance Analysis</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="pageTemplate.html" class="glow">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="pageTemplate.html" class="glow">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="pageTemplate.html" class="glow">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="pageTemplate.html" class="glow">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="publications.html" class="glow">Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="pageTemplate.html" class="glow">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
/*--- Nav Bar ---*/
nav { float: left; margin: 4px 0 0 137px; }
nav li { list-style: none; float: left; width: 113px; height: 56px; text-align: center; position: relative; }
nav li:hover { background: url(images/buttonSprite.png) 0 -90px; }
nav a { display: block; width: 113px; height: 37px; }
nav a:link { padding-top: 19px; }
/*--- Creates a delayed glowing effect on the links on hover. ---*/
nav a.glow, nav a.glow:hover, nav a.glow:focus { text-shadow: none; -webkit-transition: 300ms linear 0s; -moz-transition: 300ms linear 0s; -o-transition: 300ms linear 0s; transition: 300ms linear 0s;  outline: 0 none; }  
nav a.glow:hover, nav a.glow:focus { color: #fff; text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff; }
/*--- Drop Down Functionality. ---*/
nav li ul { list-style: none; height: 0px;}
nav li ul li, nav li ul li a { height: 0px; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; tranistion: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
nav li ul li { float: none; width: 263px; background: url(images/buttonSprite.png) 0 -30px; }
nav li ul a:link { display: block; white-space: nowrap; padding-top: 0px; width: 100%; margin: -10px 0 0 0; }
/*--- Show drop-down on hover. ---*/
nav li:hover ul li { height: 30px; } 
nav li:hover ul a:link { padding-top: 6px; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 0; }
nav li ul li:hover{ background: url(images/buttonSprite.png) 0 -60px; }
```

The drop-down 'subMenu' is contained as an unordered list within its parent list item. After toying with the code, I found that setting

`nav li ul li { display: block }`

Will cause chrome and Safari to reveal the text as well. As a helper here is pictures of what I'm talking about.

Chrome: What I want:

[image]

Firefox: Not so much:

[image]

Menu down, working on all browsers I've tested:

[image]

Thanks in advance. And also, I'm quite new with this stuff so if there is formatting conventions or unnecessary code please let me know so I can write better code. I took the CSS formatting style from Apple.com's styleSheets as it seems slightly nicer than the

```
itemReference {
    attribute: setting;
}
```

style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're setting a too-small height on a list item but not setting `overflow:hidden` or anything.  Then you run into this WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33094 and get incorrect rendering in Chrome and Safari while other browsers are rendering this per spec.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you, I should have thought of trying something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Once lesson I've learned when styling lists: other than `display`, `position` and `float`, do not put any styling on `LI`, put it all on the `A`-tag with `display:block`. 99% of your problems will go away.

Comment: I'm currently working on implementing your advice, going to take a while to work it all out haha. One thing, Should I also avoid putting li:hover and do a: hover instead?? And is there any explanation behind avoiding li?

Comment: hover on A. Once you start combining margins, padding and line-height on both the A and the LI it just becomes a nightmare to follow and debug. It also makes more semantic sense to style the element being clicked, rather than its container.

Comment: Take a peek at my tutorial: preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists

Comment: Is it a crime to set the width on the li elements, as they are containers? Because my sub-menu is wider than my parent li element so without manually setting both widths I either get a way too wide parent element or way to thin sub-menus.

Comment: Your sub-menus should use absolute positioning, so the parent width shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh, that worked. Mostly. I guess my lack of understanding of what I'm using is showing through :S. I've got MainNavBar position to relative and my subMenu to absolute. They're widths are now unrelated. However, now my submenu's elements all stack on top of each other and present only the last li, do you know what would be causing that?

Comment: Can you please post and update on jsfiddle.net and post the URL. I'll take a look. (if you can set your image paths to full http://... on jsFiddle so I can see them that would help too.)

Comment: Here's the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9P3Ht/ , I don't know a way to put the images in so I swapped them to basic colors to make the bar visible. It is only the first menu item that drops down right now and there should be 5 items and only 1 is displayed.

Comment: Give this a try. your sub-menu UL needs absolute, not the LI. You need to hide the sub-menu by default, then show it on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/9P3Ht/1/

Comment: +1 for all the help, I appreciate it. I am still getting sub-menu showing itself in firefox, and, although still imperfect, I've most everything outside of the li elements. Do you have any intuition about what might cause 0 height elements to still be visible?

Comment: display:none instead oh height:0

Comment: This would work, but I would lose the Transition I'm going for, the overflow: hidden; trick works, thanks for all the help!